How to delete automatically migrated blobs (with Data Factory) based on original last modified data?
I have a Storage Account with a lifecycle management policy. I need to migrate the blobs in a new Storage Account and ensuring that these blobs get deleted after x days on the original last modified data. What can I do?
So far, I managed to create a Data Factory pipeline with a copy activity and I see there is a way to create a custom metadata with the original last modified data (the $$LASTMODIFIED value). What is the best way to exploit it for what I want to achieve? Is there a better/simpler solution?
I think one can use Azure Functions to delete the blob, but I have milions of blobs and a function go on timeout after 5/10 minutes.

you can use Delete activity to clean up those files/blobs

the below blog provides details :
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/working-with-the-delete-activity-in-azure-data-factory

no, I need to delete the blob based on the "old" last modified data.
